# How to compute compounded interest rate?

Tags: math, currency

I have the following scenario where i invest variable amount of principal every month,

```
Investment Month
$300       Jan
$200       Feb
$100       Mar
```

and i get a return of,

```
Returns    Month
$1000      Apr
```

How do i calculate the nominal annual interest rate if the amount is compounded monthly?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
300*(1 + p/12)^(3) + 200*(1 + p/12)^(2) + 100*(1 + p/12)^(1) == 1000
```

[Use bisection or something else to solve numericaly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300*%281%20%2b%20p/12%29%5E%283%29%20%2b%20200*%281%20%2b%20p/12%29%5E%282%29%20%2b%20100*%281%20%2b%20p/12%29%5E%281%29%20=%201000).

```
p=286%
```

EDIT:
   Best way to solve this numericaly is to apply [Newton–Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), since this equation can be simply derivated analytically.